# add points on mouseclick for jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am adding the data points to the JFreechart's XYLineChart series using the mouse listener as shown below:

```
public class ChartTest extends ApplicationFrame implements  
    ChartMouseListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
  private JFreeChart chart;
  private ChartPanel chartPanel;
  private double chartX;
  private double chartY;
  private XYSeries series = new XYSeries("High");
  private XYSeriesCollection data = new XYSeriesCollection();

  public ChartTest(String title) {
    super(title);
    String chartTitle = " ";

    this.chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(chartTitle, "X", "Y", 
            createDataset(), PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    chartPanel = new ChartPanel(this.chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 300));
    chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);
    chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(this);
    chartPanel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    chartPanel.addMouseListener(this);

  public XYDataset createDataset() {
      data.addSeries(series);
      return data;
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    int x = event.getX();
    int y = event.getY();     
    Point2D point = chartPanel.translateScreenToJava2D(new Point(x, y));
    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();

    Rectangle2D bounds = chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().getPlotInfo().getDataArea();

    RectangleEdge domainAxisEdge = plot.getDomainAxisEdge();
    RectangleEdge rangeAxisEdge = plot.getRangeAxisEdge();
    chartX = domainAxis.java2DToValue(point.getX(), bounds, 
            domainAxisEdge);
    chartY = rangeAxis.java2DToValue(point.getY(), bounds, 
            rangeAxisEdge);

    series.add(chartX, chartY);
  } 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ChartTest test = new ChartTest(
                    "Test");
                test.pack();
                RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(test);
                test.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I would like to implement the mouse dragging functionality but I'm stuck on how to implement that part. Any help on how to get started on it would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Yup I have. It works now. Cheers buddy. Just one question: would I be able to drag these buttons using this mouse listener?

Comment: Hey @trashgod, is there a way to update chart through dragging for the decimal points? I can't get the dragging to work for the decimal points e.g series.add(2.5, 5) etc. It only works when x=0 is added to the series first. When i try to drag one of these points, it throws a seriesException with message: No observation at x = .. . I want to add random points on the chart with mouse click (which I have already done) and then drag those points. How could I solve this issue?

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.